# iPhone/iPad different view orientations in different views , and apple approval process

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I would like to force my app's home screen to be Portrait and all other views to be landscape. Will apple rejects the app if I do this?

If not And how exactly I force only first screen to launch in Portrait mode? And force all other screens to launch in landscape.

This is not a duplicate question I search every possible answer for this in this website.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to force my app's home screen to be Portrait and all other views to be landscape. Will apple rejects the app if I do this?
No apple will not reject your App for this. We do have a lot of apps which doesn't support orientation. You forcing it on one screen won't cause your app to reject.

If not And how exactly I force only first screen to launch in Portrait mode? And force all other screens to launch in landscape.
For this you can over write : `-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations;` function.